# Pidgin will not disable the notifications

Tags: fedora, notifications, pidgin

I'm using Pidgin 2.10.0-1.fc14 and libpurple 2.10.0. I have completely disabled all the notifications from *Plugins*: *Libnotify Popups* and *Message Notifications*.

The problem is it still notifies every time someone is typing and a new message is received. I just want all the notifications to be shut off completely. What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

I've even removed `pidgin-libnotify` and still no effect.

Comment: Have you restarted it?

Comment: @Ketan numerous times. I don't even know the status of this issue since it's been so long ago.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you fix this. Bring out your Buddy list, under Tools choose Preferences then "Interface" tab next under "Conversation Window" you'll find Hide new IM conversations. Set it to "Always". (You might have trouble noticing new messages, but I'm thinking that's the goal)
This should affect all accounts.

Comment: That didn't do it.